# keras,backendインストール方法

Tags: python, python3, keras

コードを実装すると、下記のエラーが発生してしまいます。
そこで、`pip install keras.backend` でインストールを行いましたが、上手く行きませんでした。
どのような手順で行えば、インストールが出来、解決できるでしょうか？
大変お手数おかけしますが、ご回答お願い致します。

```
import keras
from keras.applications.imagenet_utils import preprocess_input
from keras.backend.tensorflow_backend import set_session
from keras.models import Model
from keras.preprocessing import image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.misc import imread
import tensorflow as tf
```

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-8b6965f27c29> in <module>
      1 import keras
      2 from keras.applications.imagenet_utils import preprocess_input
----> 3 from keras.backend.tensorflow_backend import set_session
      4 from keras.models import Model
      5 from keras.preprocessing import image

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.backend.tensorflow_backend'; 'keras.backend' is not a package
```

ちなみに、versionはkeras：2.4.3、tensorflow：2.4.0でございます。

Comment: しばらく放置されていた質問のようですが、こんな記事 [マルチバックエンドKerasの終焉、tf.kerasに一本化](https://atmarkit.itmedia.co.jp/ait/articles/2005/13/news017.html) と、おそらく古い版数用のこんなガイド [インストール - Home keras documentation](https://keras.io/ja/#_2) があるので、`pip install keras.backend` という手順でインストール出来る何かは存在しないのでは？ `keras.backend`というモジュールorパッケージはgoogleやPyPIで検索しても見つかりそうも無いので、「上手く行きませんでした。」というのが何か「見つからない」関連のエラーならばやり方が間違っていそうです。

Comment: 質問に対するご回答ありがとうございます！
未だに解決してないなかったので、早速試して見ます！